# Make display none all error message after 2s in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make display none all error message after 2s after the error message are displayed commonly?

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#error_message').show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

So that whenever a error message is displayed, error message want to persist 2s after it want to display out.
It is difficult to change this inside every node. So I want to write the code commonly, which will have effect in every page.
So where ever error message is displayed , it want to be displayed out in 2 seconds.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure you need the show() bit. Perhaps two commands - one to show, one to set the delay? What happens at the moment - any errors with the above code?

Comment: @Matt Gibson: Actually this code `$('#error_message').show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
` works fine for me. It will first make `display:block` make a delay of 2s and then `display:none` slowly...

Answer (score 1):

If you do this on document.ready it will be executed once, not everytime you display an error message.

Implement the delayed fadeOut with an function to display the error.

```
function display_error(message) {
    $('#error_message').html(message);
    $('#error_message').show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

If this doesn't work or is not suitable, you can also bind it to an event and trigger the event on display.

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/28XTM/

Comment: Here I need to call this function every where the error comes. Is there anyway where ever `#error_message` is displayed, it want to be displayed out in 2s without call the function every where.

Answer (score 0):

To hide error using '#error_message' as id but if you have more than one elements then you should use '.error_message' as a class instead of id.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#error_message').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow'); // For id and use $('.error_message') for class
    //Or
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#error_message').fadeOut('slow'); // For id and use $('.error_message') for class
    }, 2000)
});​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8C4EQ/1/).

Never use id $("#someId") for more than one element, it should be unique instead use class $(".someClass") when you have something like that

```
<div class="someClass">This is an error.</div>
<div class="someClass">This is an error.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajaxError event handler for show the error of all ajax calls in your project. Just paste this code to your layout page:

```
$(function(){
     $(".error_message").ajaxError(function (event, xhr, status, error) {
           $(this).html(error).show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using setTimeout:

```
<div id="error_message">
     Put your error message here
</div>

<button id="btn_error">Show error</button>

<script>

// Init sample
$('#error_message').hide();

function display_error(message) {
    $('#error_message').html(message);
    $('#error_message').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#error_message').hide();
    }, 2000);
}

$("#btn_error").click(function() {
    display_error("Show this test message");
});
</script>
```